# Mysql Forward engineer errno 150

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1005

I'm modeling my db shema using MySQL Workbench CE EER modeler and now I'm stuck with mysql errno 150.

My sql code:

```
CREATE  TABLE `myschema`.`Clients` (
  `phone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  `surname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `middleName` VARCHAR(30) NULL ,
  `discountCardNumber` BIGINT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`phone`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `discountCardNumber_UNIQUE` (`discountCardNumber` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Clients_DiscountCards1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`discountCardNumber` )
    REFERENCES `myschema`.`DiscountCards` (`cardNumber` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE `myschema`.`OrderStatuses` (
  `statusID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `statusTitle` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `statusDescription` VARCHAR(150) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`statusID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myschema`.`WorkstationUsers` (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `pass` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `surname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `middleName` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `myschema`.`Orders` (
  `orderID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `registerDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `clientPhone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  `shipmentAddress` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
  `orderStatus` INT NOT NULL ,
  `registrator` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Orders_Clients` (`clientPhone` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_Orders_OrderStatuses1` (`orderStatus` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_Orders_WorkstationUsers1` (`registrator` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_Clients`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientPhone` )
    REFERENCES `myschema`.`Clients` (`phone` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_OrderStatuses1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`orderStatus` )
    REFERENCES `myschema`.`OrderStatuses` (`statusID` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_WorkstationUsers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`registrator` )
    REFERENCES `myschema`.`WorkstationUsers` (`userID` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

It fails in last statement (`CREATE TABLE Orders`).

I already checked:

- Types of refferencing tables are equals
- Indexes on all columns exists
- Engine is `InnoDB`

Thanks for any help! Have a good day!

P.S. sorry for possible duplicate. I really can't find any problem in my code.

Comment: Where is the table DiscountCards?

Comment: @AshwinA it exists, but everything ok with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of fields are defined as NOT NULL, but you defined 'ON DELETE' action as 'SET NULL'.

Make these fields nullabe -

```
CREATE TABLE `myschema`.`Orders` (
  `orderID` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `registerDate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `clientPhone` VARCHAR(15) NULL, -- NOT NULL ,
  `shipmentAddress` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL ,
  `orderStatus` INT NULL, -- NOT NULL ,
  `registrator` INT NULL, -- NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_Orders_Clients` (`clientPhone` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_Orders_OrderStatuses1` (`orderStatus` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_Orders_WorkstationUsers1` (`registrator` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_Clients`
    FOREIGN KEY (`clientPhone` )
    REFERENCES `myschema`.`Clients` (`phone` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_OrderStatuses1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`orderStatus` )
    REFERENCES `myschema`.`OrderStatuses` (`statusID` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Orders_WorkstationUsers1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`registrator` )
    REFERENCES `myschema`.`WorkstationUsers` (`userID` )
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved by adding

> DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

at the end of each create table

regards!